# make my apps music/sfx stop if background audio is playing from a different app?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm looking to achieve the opposite effect of AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbientSolo.

Currently my options seem to be stick with solo(default) and have my app stop any pre playing music/sfx and play my apps music/sfx

or

I can use Ambient and have background audio mix with my apps music/sfx.

The effect I want is the opposite of solo. If the user is playing music or listening to a podcast from another app, then I dont want my app to play any sound. If the user isn't listening to anything else and starts my app, then my app can play it's music/sfx.

Seems ambient and solo are my only options unless I'm missing something.

If it has any bearing I'm using spritekit and swift.